Conjectures involving $\Lambda(n)$
As the title suggests, I am looking for conjectures involving the Von Mangoldt function, $\Lambda(n)$. I understand this is not a rigorous mathematical question, however if reference requests for conjectures and theorems are permitted, then I humbly ask this question to be considered and approved here. I will make sure to include appropriate tags. I am looking specifically for conjectures that can be written in terms of $\Lambda(n)$, like for example: Goldbach's conjecture rewritten, or conjectures about the nature of $\Lambda(n)$. The reason is to attempt solving something in number theory, and find $\Lambda(n)$ to have some nice analytic properties/connections to the broader number theory. Thank you

To my untrained eyes there seems to be one at https://oeis.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function.

@Aruralreader If I'm not mistaken, it conjectures that $$\text{GCD}(\binom{n}{1}, \binom{n}{2}, \ldots, \binom{n}{n-1}) = e^{\Lambda(n)}$$, right? I have never seen this before. Thank you for pointing this out +1

@Aruralreader It seems a consequence of this, nevertheless interesting though

Virtually every conjecture about primes can be rephrased in terms of the von Mangoldt function. For example, the quantitative twin primes conjecture is equivalent to an asymptotic formula for $\sum_{n\le x} \Lambda(n)\Lambda(n+2)$.

@GregMartin Well aware, it is what I'm looking for :)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153697/the-goldbach-conjecture-and-hardy-littlewood-asymptotic#:~:text=Here%2C%20Λ(n)%20denotes,behaviour%20may%20depend%20on%20A.

The following has been proven by joriki and GH from MO:
$$n>1:$$
$$\Lambda(n)=\lim\limits_{s \rightarrow 1} \zeta(s)\sum\limits_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^{(s-1)}}$$
$$a(n) = -\lim\limits_{s \rightarrow 1} \zeta(s)\sum\limits_{d|n} \mu(d)(e^{d})^{(s-1)}$$
$$T(n,k) = a(GCD(n,k))$$
$$\displaystyle T = \begin{bmatrix} +1&+1&+1&+1&+1&+1&+1&\cdots \\ +1&-1&+1&-1&+1&-1&+1 \\ +1&+1&-2&+1&+1&-2&+1 \\ +1&-1&+1&-1&+1&-1&+1 \\ +1&+1&+1&+1&-4&+1&+1 \\ +1&-1&-2&-1&+1&+2&+1 \\ +1&+1&+1&+1&+1&+1&-6 \\ \vdots&&&&&&&\ddots \end{bmatrix}$$
which gives a symmetric expansion of the von Mangoldt function:
$$\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{T(1,1)}{1 \cdot 1}&+\frac{T(1,2)}{1 \cdot 2}&+\frac{T(1,3)}{1 \cdot 3}+&\cdots&+\frac{T(1,k)}{1 \cdot k} \\
\frac{T(2,1)}{2 \cdot 1}&+\frac{T(2,2)}{2 \cdot 2}&+\frac{T(2,3)}{2 \cdot 3}+&\cdots&+\frac{T(2,k)}{2 \cdot k} \\
\frac{T(3,1)}{3 \cdot 1}&+\frac{T(3,2)}{3 \cdot 2}&+\frac{T(3,3)}{3 \cdot 3}+&\cdots&+\frac{T(3,k)}{3 \cdot k} \\
 \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\
\frac{T(n,1)}{n \cdot 1}&+\frac{T(n,2)}{n \cdot 2}&+\frac{T(n,3)}{n \cdot 3}+&\cdots&+\frac{T(n,k)}{n \cdot k} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\infty}{1} \\ +\frac{\Lambda(2)}{2} \\ +\frac{\Lambda(3)}{3} \\ \vdots \\ +\frac{\Lambda(n)}{n} \end{bmatrix}$$
$$=\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$$
$$\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\infty}{1}&+\frac{\Lambda(2)}{2}&+\frac{\Lambda(3)}{3}+&\cdots&+\frac{\Lambda(k)}{k} \end{bmatrix}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$$
The generating function for the matrix $T$ is:
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{T(n,k)}{n^c \cdot k^s} = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\lim\limits_{z \rightarrow s} \zeta(z)\sum\limits_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^{(z-1)}}}{n^c} = \frac{\zeta(s) \zeta(c)}{\zeta(s + c - 1)}$$
The generating function for the main diagonal of the matrix $T$ is: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{T(n,n)}{n^s}=\frac{\zeta (s)}{\zeta (s-1)}$$
Set $c=s$ and add the generating functions together and take the limit:
$$\underset{s\to 1}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{\zeta (s) \zeta (s)}{\zeta (s+s-1)}+\frac{\zeta (s)}{\zeta (s-1)}\right)=-2 \gamma+2 \log (2 \pi )$$
But that is not the same as the reciprocal sum over the zeta zeros:
RH Equivalence 5.3, page 6. The Riemann Hypothesis is equivalent to the equality:
$$\sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{|\rho|^2} =\sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{\rho (1{-}\rho)}= 2 + \gamma - \log (4\pi)$$
where the sum is over all complex zeros $$ρ = β + iγ$$ of $$ζ(s)$$ in the critical strip $$0 < β < 1$$.
Edit 21.8.2024:
The Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to:
$$\underset{\text{factor}}{-2}\left(\underset{\text{non-trivial zeros}}{\sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{\rho (1{-}\rho)}} + \underset{\text{trivial zeros}}{\sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{-2k(1-(-2k))}} - \underset{\text{the pole}}{1}\right)= \underset{s\to 1}{\text{lim}}\left(\underset{\text{the whole matrix}}{\frac{\zeta (s) \zeta (s)}{\zeta (s+s-1)}}+\underset{\text{main diagonal}}{\frac{\zeta (s)}{\zeta (s-1)}}\right)$$
Where:
$$\underset{\text{the whole matrix}}{\frac{\zeta (s) \zeta (s)}{\zeta (s+s-1)}}$$ is a Dirichlet generating function which when evaluated at $s=1$ as in the limit (above) is the symmetric expansion of the von Mangoldt function above.

Series expansions in Mathematica 14:


Limit[Zeta[s]*Zeta[s]/Zeta[s + s - 1] + Zeta[s]/Zeta[s - 1],    s -> 1] == -2  EulerGamma + 2  Log[2  \[Pi]]

$$\underset{s\to 1}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{\zeta (s) \zeta (s)}{\zeta (s+s-1)}+\frac{\zeta (s)}{\zeta (s-1)}\right)=-2 \gamma+2 \log (2 \pi )$$
$$\sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{|\rho|^2} =\sum_{\rho} \frac{1}{\rho (1{-}\rho)}= 2 + \gamma - \log (4\pi)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{k=\infty} \frac{1}{-2k(1-(-2k))} = \log (2)-1$$

Excel recurrence for T: =IF(OR(ROW()=1; COLUMN()=1); 1; IF(ROW()>=COLUMN();-SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-COLUMN()+1;COLUMN(); 4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1; COLUMN(); 4); 4));-SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COLUMN()-ROW()+1;ROW(); 4)&":"&ADDRESS(COLUMN()-1; ROW(); 4); 4))))
or with different separator commas:
=IF(OR(ROW()=1, COLUMN()=1), 1, IF(ROW()>=COLUMN(),-SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-COLUMN()+1,COLUMN(), 4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW()-1, COLUMN(), 4), 4)),-SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COLUMN()-ROW()+1,ROW(), 4)&":"&ADDRESS(COLUMN()-1, ROW(), 4), 4)))) Excel formula translator: https://de.excel-translator.de/translator/

I greatly appreciate all the effort you've put into this post. I wish I could like this answer twice!

Thank you for the kind words!

Normal[Series[Zeta[s]*Zeta[s]/Zeta[s + s - 1], {s, 1, 0}]]
Series1
Normal[Series[Zeta[s]/Zeta[s - 1], {s, 1, 0}]]
Series2
